# Does Bakshi, Kapadia and Madan (2003) VIX building approach underestimate volatility?

Tags: options, volatility, vix

From a paper that shortly addresses an alternative approach to VIX-like index building:

[image]

[image]

To test this approach, I've built a fake book of B&S options with constant volatility equal to $\sigma=20\%$, $0\%$ risk free rate and $0\%$ cost of carry. I focused my attention on $T=15$ days maturity (roughly $0.0411$ years on $365$ basis).

[image]

Starting from the assumption that Bakshi, Kapadia and Madan (2003) approach is correct, one should get as a result a VIX-like object whose value is equal to $20\%$ if he applied the formula to the book above.

From partial moments to VIX-like value with fake $\sigma=20\%$ options:

```
H1  =   0,001647398
H2  =   -4,6183E-06
H3  =   7,30375E-06
mu  =   -0,000823234
VAR =   0,040070196
VIX =   sqrt(VAR) = 20%
```

My VBA code so you can easily reproduce my results:

```
Public Function VAR_T(F As Double, K_C As Range, K_P As Range, C As Range, P As Range, rf As Double, t As Double) As Double

    ' F         Underlying forward value
    ' K_C       Range of Call options' strike prices
    ' K_P       Range of Put options' strike prices
    ' C         Range of Call options' prices (same extent of K_C is mandatory)
    ' P         Range of Put options' prices (same extent of K_P is mandatory)
    ' rf        Risk free rate (as instance of EUR, EONIA spot is suggested)
    ' t         Time to expiry in years on 365 basis

    Dim kH1 As Double
    Dim kmu_t As Double

    kH1 = H1_T(F, K_C, K_P, C, P)
    kmu_t = mu_T(F, K_C, K_P, C, P, rf, t)
    VAR_T = (Exp(rf * t) * kH1 - (kmu_t) ^ 2) / t

    ' Squared root of VAR_T is the underlying volatility on expiry date equal to today + t

End Function

Public Function mu_T(F As Double, K_C As Range, K_P As Range, C As Range, P As Range, rf As Double, t As Double) As Double

    Dim kH1 As Double
    Dim kH2 As Double
    Dim kH3 As Double

    kH1 = H1_T(F, K_C, K_P, C, P)
    kH2 = H2_T(F, K_C, K_P, C, P)
    kH3 = H3_T(F, K_C, K_P, C, P)

    mu_T = Exp(rf * t) - 1 - Exp(rf * t) / 2 * kH1 - Exp(rf * t) / 6 * kH2 - Exp(rf * t) / 24 * kH3

End Function

Public Function H1_T(F As Double, K_C As Range, K_P As Range, C As Range, P As Range) As Double

    Dim n_C As Integer
    Dim n_P As Integer
    Dim partial_moment_C()
    Dim partial_moment_P()

    n_C = K_C.Count
    n_P = K_P.Count

    ReDim partial_moment_C(n_C)
    ReDim partial_moment_P(n_P)

    For i = 1 To n_C
        partial_moment_C(i) = 2 * (1 - Log(K_C(i) / F)) / (K_C(i) ^ 2) * C(i)
    Next

    For i = 1 To n_P
        partial_moment_P(i) = 2 * (1 + Log(F / K_P(i))) / (K_P(i) ^ 2) * P(i)
    Next

    H1_T = Application.Sum(partial_moment_C) + Application.Sum(partial_moment_P)

End Function

Public Function H2_T(F As Double, K_C As Range, K_P As Range, C As Range, P As Range) As Double

    Dim n_C As Integer
    Dim n_P As Integer
    Dim partial_moment_C()
    Dim partial_moment_P()

    n_C = K_C.Count
    n_P = K_P.Count

    ReDim partial_moment_C(n_C)
    ReDim partial_moment_P(n_P)

    For i = 1 To n_C
        partial_moment_C(i) = (6 * Log(K_C(i) / F) - 3 * (Log(K_C(i) / F)) ^ 2) / (K_C(i) ^ 2) * C(i)
    Next

    For i = 1 To n_P
        partial_moment_P(i) = (6 * Log(F / K_P(i)) + 3 * (Log(F / K_P(i))) ^ 2) / (K_P(i) ^ 2) * P(i)
    Next

    H2_T = Application.Sum(partial_moment_C) - Application.Sum(partial_moment_P)

End Function

Public Function H3_T(F As Double, K_C As Range, K_P As Range, C As Range, P As Range) As Double

    Dim n_C As Integer
    Dim n_P As Integer
    Dim partial_moment_C()
    Dim partial_moment_P()

    n_C = K_C.Count
    n_P = K_P.Count

    ReDim partial_moment_C(n_C)
    ReDim partial_moment_P(n_P)

    For i = 1 To n_C
        partial_moment_C(i) = (12 * (Log(K_C(i) / F)) ^ 2 - 4 * (Log(K_C(i) / F)) ^ 3) / (K_C(i) ^ 2) * C(i)
    Next

    For i = 1 To n_P
        partial_moment_P(i) = (12 * (Log(F / K_P(i))) ^ 2 + 4 * (Log(F / K_P(i))) ^ 3) / (K_P(i) ^ 2) * P(i)
    Next

    H3_T = Application.Sum(partial_moment_C) + Application.Sum(partial_moment_P)

End Function
```

If you use the functions above to calculate the VIX-like value of the fake options, you will get $20\%$ as expected; but, if you build fake options using a huge implied volatility, something like $\sigma=80\%$, my code returns an implied model free volatility of... $62\%$!

Possibilities:

1. I am wrong with my understanding of the aforementioned formulas;
2. I am wrong with the implementation of the aforementioned formulas in VBA code;
3. Bakshi, Kapadia and Madan (2003) approach underestimate volatility, which sounds unlikely... what am I not taking into account?

Comment: conjecture: yes, I believe VIX underestimates volatility, and it uses historical data to determine future volatility

Comment: I'm not able to figure out what you mean when you say that VIX uses historical data.

Comment: I'm sorry, the VIX itself doesn't use historical data, Implied Volatility does. The price of an option effects the VIX, and the price of VIX effects unrelated option's implied volatility

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your implementation, you are approximating continuous integrals over the strike domain by Riemann sums. This introduces an error.

More specifically, for a fixed time to expiry $\tau$, you're integrating (scaled) OTM price curves (see equations $(3)-(4)-(5)$). As volatility increases, these curves will stretch over *wider and wider spatial domains*.

When using a *fixed strike range* for approximating the integrals, the truncation error will therefore mechanically increase as you will less and less be able to capture what happens in the `tails'.

[image]